# Show reports from a report folder in picklist

Tags: apex, visualforce, sobject

I currently have a text field on a custom object which is supposed to store a  report URL. As things are right now, the user can simply paste the URL of a report and it gets saved.

However, I want the user to be able to select the field's value from a list of reports present in a certain reports folder when creating or editing records. The user should see a picklist when creating or editing records and the picklist should list all reports present in a certain folder. Is there a way to accomplish this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you needs this only statically you can use a simple picklist and manually prepopulate the values (urls) in the setup.

If you want it dynamically (and if you are an experienced programmer) have a look at the metadata api   http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

There is an apex wrapper here  https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Alternatively you can access the api with pure javascript. That's the way I would prefer, but possibly even harder...

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this differently from Uwe Heim's answer. I compromised on storing the report ID instead of the report URL. I placed a select list on my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:selectList id="accts" value="{!myObject.Report__c}" title="Report">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!reports}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
```

In the Apex Controller, I added the following in a getReports function:

```
public List<selectOptions> getReports()
{
  List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>():
  folder[] ff = [select id from folder where developername = 'My_Reports_Folder'];

  id fid = (ff.isEmpty()) ? null : ff[0].id;

  report[] rpts = [select id, name from report where ownerid = : fid and ownerid != null order by name];

  for (int i=0; i<rpts.length; i++) {
    options.add(new selectOption(rpts[i].id, rpts[i].name));
  }
  return options;
}
```